# filter array using includes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter my array `availableSizes` and just display a certain size that I input into `includes`

I am testing with `5` and it should output just the number 5 but I am getting `this is not a function`

How can I filter this array so it will just output the numbers passed into the `includes` method?

```
 render() {
        const { id, img, name, price, desc, color, match, material, size, slug } = this.props
        const { selectedSize, showSizes } = this.state
        const availableSizes = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

    return (
      <Wrap>
        <Half>
          <ImgWrap>
          {showSizes &&
            <Sizes>

              <SizeWrap>
                <div>selecta size</div>
                {availableSizes.filter(availableSize => availableSize.includes(5)).map((availableSize, index) =>
                  <Size
                    key={index}
                    active={selectedSize === availableSize.size}
                    onClick={() => this.handleSelectSize(availableSize.size)}
                    className="snipcart-add-item"
                    data-item-id={id}
                    data-item-name={name}
                    data-item-price={price}
                    data-item-url="/"
                    data-item-size={this.state.size}
                    data-item-description={desc}
                  >
                    {availableSize}
                  </Size>
                )}
              </SizeWrap>
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking this one (likely) step further, you probably want to match available sizes to more than one value.  So if you have a user who is interested in sizes 5 and 6, you might store that in an array like: `var selectedSizes = [5, 6]`

Then you could match against the available sizes with: `availableSizes.filter(x => selectedSizes.includes(x))`

Answer (score 2):

availableSize from your filter callback will be a number. Number don't have method includes. What you should do is check if equal.

```
availableSizes.filter(availableSize => availableSize === 5)
```

And for the active prop you should

```
active={selectedSize === availableSize}
```

For the onClick also change for

```
onClick={() => this.handleSelectSize(availableSize)}
```

For multiple size you can then build an array of these sizes

```
const mySizes = [4, 5] 
availableSizes.filter(availableSize => mySizes.includes(availableSize))
```

Comment: console.log(availableSizes.includes(5)); == true, how does this work if number doesn't have this method?

Comment: availableSizes is the array. availableSize is a single number of the array availableSizes

Comment: If you look in mdn doc you will see filter callback provide you the item at certain index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: ok so say I had 2 numbers instead of just `5` how can i check if the array includes both of these number and output the results?

Comment: build an array with both number an now check with the includes. `const mySizes = [4, 5]` `availableSizes.filter(availableSize => mySizes.includes(availableSize))`